# See if a post has a specified tag

Tags: posts, search, tags

I'm trying to see if a post (thru id) has a specified tag

```
    if has_tag( $tag = 'Cat', $post = $post_id ) {
    $taganimal = "Cat";
}
```

I tried this, but it just crashes the site .

Got idea from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/, but can't get it to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your condition with brackets according to PHP syntax:

```
if (has_tag('Cat', $post_id)) {
    $taganimal = "Cat";
}
```

If you need to check multiple tags you can use something like

```
foreach (['Cat', 'Dog'] as $animal) if (has_tag($animal, $post_id)) {
    $taganimal = $animal;
    break;
}
```

but it would find only the first tag listed in array in case the post has several of them.

Comment: Yes! Sometimes I can be stuck for hours just because I forgot a space! - is there anyway to make it a "one liner?"

Comment: @JoBe Yes, since there is only one statement inside this `if` block: `if (has_tag('Cat', $post_id)) $taganimal = "Cat";`

Comment: what's best "praxis" if I for example should check the tag for 20 animals, write 20 one-liners  or use else if statement?

Comment: @JoBe Updated the answer.

Comment: that one didn't WordPress like, that got fatal...  Only the first tag.. you mean if I got cat and dog on the same post?

Comment: @JoBe Sorry, missed closing bracket, fixed. Yes, I mean if your post has both tags, `$taganimal` value would be the first tag. What is desired behavior?

Comment: Thx, the function is to get the species of members pets into their mail, and usually a cat is a cat, unless they are having some kind of identity issue. So every post should only have one of these tags inside..